# Couple of registry questions regarding Inno Setup

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, registry, inno-setup, windows-7-x64

I'm setting a new app with Inno Setup, and I have some questions please:

I have to enter new values into Windows registry.
I've tried this but it does not seem to work:

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\Software\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\ContextMenus\MsExplorer\MenuTable\502"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Text"; ValueData: "Test 1";
```

So I'd like to ask:

1. Should I add a new entry just before, that creates "502" entry?
2. Alternatively, I may use "regedit /s" to enter these values. What way is better when using Inno Setup?
3. Besides, I'd like to ask the user during the installation, if he wants to add these values. I understand that I have to use [Tasks] entries, but still can't understand how to use it. Can you provide an example?

I have to support Win XP and Win7 (32 and 64bit), so if there is any differentiation, please let me know about.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create the keys explicitly as that is done implicitly when you write the value.
You should use the `[registry]` section as Inno can then remove the values on uninstall.

If this is installing on a 64-bit machine note that the entries will (by default) be written to the 32-bit view of the registry which you can see in regedit under:
`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\ContextMenus\MsExplorer\MenuTable\502`
Microsoft [KB896459](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896459) explains the changes in more details.

(Also note that `HKLM/SYSTEM/Software` is NOT the same as `HKLM/Software` with the latter being the usual one.)

You can also find samples of `[tasks]` in the help under `[tasks]`.